# Prevent scrollbar from hiding on froyo

Tags: android

Starting with 2.2, scrollbars would disappear once the scrolling has stopped.
Is there a way to make them always visible like before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [`View.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(boolean fadeScrollbars)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29)? This is available since API level 5.

Answer (score 3):

A helper method:

```
public static void disableScrollbarFading(View view) {
    try {
        Method setScrollbarFadingEnabled = View.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                "setScrollbarFadingEnabled", boolean.class);
        setScrollbarFadingEnabled.setAccessible(true);
        setScrollbarFadingEnabled.invoke(view, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // OK, API level < 5
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked just perfectly for me. No thinking required, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this in the xml with android:fadeScrollbars="false".