# How to make the scrollbars of listview visible all the time

Tags: android, android-listview

I want my scrollbars to be visible all the time, well only the vertical scroll bar.

I google this and I found this tag `android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"` but this works fine when you have a scroll view but when I add this as a tag in my `ListView` then eclipse it telling me that this tag doesn't exist in the `ListView`-component.

Is there any way to make the scroll bars of the `ListView` widget to be visible all the time ?

Edit1:
these are all my tags and values of the listview

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list" android:clickable="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:fastScrollEnabled="true" android:scrollbars="vertical
```

The scroll is shown but only when I am scrolling and after few seconds it is gone

Comment: do you have in your xml android:scrollbars="visible"????

Comment: I have android:scrollbars="vertical" I tried with visible but eclipse says that 'visible' is not supported

Comment: try this android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000000000"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent scrollbar from hiding on froyo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861956/prevent-scrollbar-from-hiding-on-froyo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set android:fadeScrollbars="false"

Comment: I fix this , but it was long time ago. Now android with the new api versions works bather , and there are a lot fixes to issues that existed before.

Answer (score 0):

Will enabling [android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack) for the `ListView` do the trick?